# SharePoint:You do not have permissions to perform this operation. Please contact your system administrator

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am having a SharePoint site and I am getting the below access error only for the first time. 
Error : "You do not have permissions to perform this operation. Please contact your system administrator".

if I refresh the page its working fine and again if I close the browser and reopens it again it throws the same above error and works fine i refresh the page.

i check eventvwr for logs. but i didn't find any logs for that. I am unable to figure it out why it is showing this access error only for the first time. Can any one please suggest me how to check or how to resolve this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

please remove your id from hidden SharePoint list(MembershipGroupId=0) and add again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@sree we faced exactly same issue in our environment. Please check hardened policies on your server. Sharepoint doesn't go well with it.

Especially policies which enable **FIPS** algorithm.